# Keypress event not triggered sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keycode, onkeypress

When I hit ~ and some other punctuation keys ('``´) , the `keypress` event is not triggered.

This makes my attempt to get the `keycode` and the `String.fromCharCode` fail and thus my validation fails as well. I need to return false when my script detects these chars

Is there a way to this to work? Is there a workaround?

Obs: I'm using Chromium on Ubuntu

Comment: can you show us some code/snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use **keydown** for this

you can know more about it here : https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

```
$("#id").keydown(function(ev){ console.log(ev); });
```